# taking information from a structure and using in another function

Tags: c, function, structure

I need to know if I can call the information that is in tire_pressure in the structure and use it in another function? Basically I am not sure how to call it from one to the other. Do I have to declare the function in tireTest? Which is the function I am trying to access the tire_pressure information at. Thanks for the help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


struct tires
{
    char Manufacturer[40];
    int tire_pressure[0];
    int pressure_change[0];
}typedef tires;
// Prototypes
void getTireInformation(tires*, int);
void tirePressure(tires*, int);
void tireTest(tires*, int);
int main()
{
    tires tire[4];
    tires* ptire = &tire[0];
    srand(time(NULL));

    getTireInformation(ptire, 4);
    tirePressure(ptire, 4);
    tireTest(ptire, 4);

    return 0;
}// end main
//============================
void getTireInformation(tires* ptire, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter Make for the tire: \n");
        scanf("%s", &(ptire + i) ->Manufacturer);


    }

    printf("all tire make you entered ...just for verification:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%s\n",(ptire +i) ->Manufacturer);

}//end getTireInformation
//=======================================================================

void tirePressure(tires* ptire, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int min = 18;
    int max = 35;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        (ptire + i) ->tire_pressure[0] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
        printf("The Tire pressure is: ");
        printf("%d\n",(ptire + i) -> tire_pressure[0]);
    }// end for
}// end tirePressure
//==============================================================
void tireTest(tires* ptire, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int min = 2;
    int max = 5;
    int change[0] = {0};
    i++;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        change[0] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
        //(ptire + i) -> pressure_change[0] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
        printf("Pressure change from test %d: %d\n",i + 1, change[0]);
        //(ptire + i) -> pressure_change[0] = change[0] + tirePressure;
        //printf("%d\n", (ptire +i) -> pressure_change);
    }// end for

}
```

Comment: You must not access `(ptire + i) ->tire_pressure[0]` and `change[0]` since the arrays have only zero elements. Note: creating arrays having zero elements isn't supported in the standard.

Comment: @MikeCAT so if the array was to have say 2 elements would it work?

Comment: You invoked *undefine behavior* by passing a pointer pointing at an object having wrong data type: `%s` calls for `char*`, but you passed `char (*)[40]` in `scanf("%s", &(ptire + i) ->Manufacturer);`

Comment: What is "work"? The code might not work well because there is a unused argument `ptire` in `tireTest()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making the problem more difficult than it is -- see if this simplification solves your problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PRESSURE_MIN 18
#define PRESSURE_MAX 35

struct tires
{
    char Manufacturer[40];
    int tire_pressure;
    int pressure_change;
} typedef tires;

// Prototypes
void getTireInformation(tires *, int);
void tirePressure(tires *, int);
void tireTest(tires *, int);

//===============================================================

void getTireInformation(tires *ptire, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter Make for the tire: \n");
        scanf("%s", ptire[i].Manufacturer);
    }

    printf("all the tire makes you entered ... just for verification:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptire[i].Manufacturer);
    }

} // end getTireInformation

//===============================================================

void tirePressure(tires *ptire, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptire[i].tire_pressure = rand() % (PRESSURE_MAX - PRESSURE_MIN + 1) + PRESSURE_MIN;
        printf("The Tire pressure is: ");
        printf("%d\n", ptire[i].tire_pressure);
    } // end for
} // end tirePressure

//==============================================================

void tireTest(tires *ptire, int size)
{
    int min = 2;
    int max = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int change = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;

        printf("Pressure change from test %d: %d\n", i + 1, change);

        ptire[i].pressure_change = change + ptire[i].tire_pressure;

        printf("%d\n", ptire[i].pressure_change);
    } // end for
}

//===============================================================

int main()
{
    tires tire[4];

    srand(time(NULL));

    getTireInformation(tire, 4);
    tirePressure(tire, 4);
    tireTest(tire, 4);

    return 0;
} // end main
```

Comment: @cdiane I did not even think about making int min and int max a constant. I think I have been working on this for so long i am starting to over thinking things